# Generate an Image with text using c#

Tags: c#, image, generator

Basically I want to be able to somehow generate an image that has a list of stats for a player. I need to be able to draw text onto the image and maybe the players avatar onto it if possible. I also want to avoid using any libraries unless I have to unless you have an easy way to do this using X library. I know how to make this using a simple php request since most of the information will be retrieved from various databases anyway, but I would prefer to have a way to make it directly in the program so I can change it easily. I've done this in java before but don't know how to make it in c# without using openGL. Here's a picture of what it might look like.

[image]

I apologize if this has been asked before but if it was I couldn't find it.

Comment: For C# on Mono, please read about the different implementations. On Linux, the Cairo implementation should be used. http://www.mono-project.com/Drawing

Comment: Mono Cairo show text example http://www.mono-project.com/Mono.Cairo_Tutorial#Show_Text_.2F_Glyphs

Comment: Just what I was looking for. Is there a way to draw without creating a window by using some sort of screen buffer or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to refer to System.Drawing namespace. GDI+ is slightly easy thing to understand and use it. This is a very easy [example](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/39219/A-Beginner-s-Primer-on-Drawing-Graphics-using-the)

Comment: This looks a bit easier than cario but can I do this offscreen or do I need to draw in a form? If i can this will be perfect.

Comment: You can create a borderless transparent topmost window or use Graphics g = Graphics.FromHwnd(IntPtr.Zero) - it will return you the graphics of the desktop.